# Create folder for the parent name dynamically

Tags: linux, bash, unix, makefile, gnu-make

I Need to create dir based on the parent directory

For example:

If I’ve project like following

```
project1
-File1
-Makefile
```

In the make file I want to do something like the following

`mkdir project1`

And then it should look like

```
project1
-File1
-Makefile
-project1
```

But I want to do it dynamically i.e. `mkdir parent folder`, since let's assume that in the makefile I **don’t know** what is the name of the parent folder. Is it possible? It should be empty folder with the name of the parent folder.

As prerequisite it should always have parent a folder

I tried the suggestion below:

**update**

```
all: build

build:
    mkdir $(basename "$PWD")
```

This created the following:

```
project1
-File1
-Makefile
-WD
```

This created a folder under the root, which is OK ,but the name is `WD` , which is wrong, it should be `project1`

Comment: `mkdir $(basename "$PWD")`?

Comment: You want to create the parent folder of the current folder? But it exists already, else you could not be in the current folder... I don't understand.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - I want to create another empty folder with the `name` of the `parent folder` but lets assume I dont have the name, I know just that I need to go one level up to read the name and then create it

Comment: @Cyrus - i'll try it now, in addition how should I get the the name into variable ?

Comment: I see. Perhaps could you reformulate your question such that it becomes crystal clear? Anyway, Cyrus' comment is what you need.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - sure, i'll try

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - no it doesnt work , it create dir with name `WD` , is there somehting missing? see my update

Comment: @Cyrus - it dosnt work but its probably the right way, please see my update, any idea why?

Comment: @shopiaT: Cyrus solution is almost correct, just double the `$` sign (`"$$PWD"`) or use `"$(PWD)"` or `"$$(pwd)"`. But it suffers two drawbacks: 1. it calls the shell while this is not needed in most cases 2. It works only if you invoke make from the directory in which your Makefile resides. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume:

1. That you are using GNU make.
2. That you have only "*reasonable*" file and directory names without spaces, special characters or even worse. If you name your makefile "`my favorite make file`", what follows will not work.
3. That you want to create your sub-directory in the directory that contains your Makefile.

First, you need to get the path and the base name of the directory that contains your Makefile. And this is not that simple. The following should work in all cases, except if you put your Makefile at the root `/` of your filesystem or have "*unreasonable*" file and directory names. Put this at the beginning of your Makefile, before any `include` directive:

```
DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
BASE := $(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(DIR)))
DIRNAME := $(DIR)$(BASE)
```

Sorry, it looks over-complicated, but all parts are here for a good reason (see at the end for the details). If you really want this to work in all cases, you need them all.

Next you need to create the sub-directory without error, even if it exists already:

```
$(DIRNAME):
    mkdir -p $@
```

`$@`, in the recipe, expands as the target, that is `$(DIRNAME)` in this case; using these automatic variables whenever possible is highly recommended. Do not forget the `-p` option, else the recipe will fail if the sub-directory exists.

Finally, you must guarantee that the command is executed before you actually need the sub-directory. Assume, for instance, that you have an `all` target but you want the sub-directory to exist before building the `all` target. You could write a simple dependency:

```
all: $(DIRNAME)
    <all-recipe>

$(DIRNAME):
    mkdir -p $@
```

But in this case, every time the content of the sub-directory is modified, you will rebuild the `all` target, possibly uselessly. This is where [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) are useful. They must exist but their last modification date is not considered by make.

All in all, the following should do what you want:

```
DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
BASE := $(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(DIR)))
DIRNAME := $(DIR)$(BASE)

all: | $(DIRNAME)
    <all-recipe>

$(DIRNAME):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Note the `|` that introduces the order-only prerequisites.

Explanation about building the name of the sub-directory that you want to create:

1. You can invoke make from a different directory:

   ```
   make -C <path-to-project>
   make -f <path-to-project>/Makefile
   ```

   So, `$(shell basename "$$PWD")` or any variant (e.g. `$(notdir $(PWD))`) will work only if you invoke make from the directory where your Makefile resides. The correct way to get the absolute path of the Makefile, even if make is invoked from elsewhere, is `$(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))`. Remember to put it before any `include` directive. Example of expansion result: `/home/john/project1/Makefile`.
2. `$(dir <some-path>)` keeps only the directory part, removing the file part. Example: `/home/john/project1/`.
3. `$(patsubst %/,%,<some-path>)` removes the trailing `/`, if any. Example: `/home/john/project1`.
4. `$(notdir <some-path>)` removes the directory part up to and including the last `/`. Example: `project1`.

So, if your Makefile is `/home/john/project1/Makefile`, and even if you call make from anywhere else than `/home/john/project1` with `make -C` or `make -f`, the `DIR`, `BASE` and `DIRNAME` variables will expand as:

```
DIR: /home/john/project1/
BASE: project1
DIRNAME: /home/john/project1/project1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
BASE := $(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(DIR)))
DIRNAME := $(DIR)$(BASE)` is better then use from `PARENT_DIR=$(shell basename "$(PWD)")` , just to verify :)

Comment: Now I read it second time :)  it seems that its better :) , also for `mac/linux/windows` ?

Comment: Btw what is `MAKEFILE_LIST` ?

Comment: @shopiaT `MAKEFILE_LIST` is the list of all Makefiles that make parsed, in parsing order. To get a complete description visit [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables).

Comment: @shopiaT: for Linux, no problem as long as you use GNU make. For Mac also but it could be that you must install GNU make with [Mac Ports](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Sorry, I cannot test, I don't have a Mac here at the moment. And for Windows, I am very sorry, I do not use it at all. But I am pretty sure that GNU make is ported on it, one way or another (`cygwin` or equivalent?).